# How to get response from CustomTabs in react-native

Tags: react-native, response

I have added CustomTabs in my app to redirect on external url. I want to get response from url that is opened in CustomTabs in my app and CustomTabs would be close automatically. url that is opened return array and I want to use array in my app.
code for custom tab:-

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/newtest.php';
CustomTabs.openURL(url,{ toolbarColor: '#607D8B',enableUrlBarHiding: true,showPageTitle: true,enableDefaultShare: true,animations: ANIMATIONS_SLIDE}).then((launched: boolean) => {                                             
console.log(`Launched custom tabs: ${launched}`);
}).catch(err => {
console.error(err)
});
```

I have no idea. what can i do for this ?

Comment: which package is `CustomTabs` from?

Comment: import {CustomTabs,ANIMATIONS_SLIDE,ANIMATIONS_FADE} from 'react-native-custom-tabs';

Comment: how can i get array from custom tab in my app

Comment: in custom tab file success.php returns an array and i want to fetch this array in my .js file inside app and custom tab would be closed automatically.

Comment: anyone help me ??

Comment: can i get url from CustomTabs ?

Comment: how can i do this ??